# iOS - Can application send and receive messages to/from server?

Tags: ios, authentication, sms, server

I'm working on an iOS project. For this project I need an authentication system. However, if it's possible I don't want to use already built two-factor authentication systems such as Plivo or Sinch. I want to implement this feature of our application.

For this purpose, I need three things:

1. My application should get the phone number of the user and send it to server.
2. Server should send a sms to the number of user and my application should be able to read this message to get authentication code sent by server.
3. Application should be able to remove messages of this procedure from inbox and outbox of the iPhone used by user.

Now, i'm asking that can I implement this feature? I know this is a weird question but i've searched the Internet all day and could not get a certain answer. Thus I'll appreciate if someone informs me shortly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes, you can that.
2. Your app can't read SMS messages received through the Messages app. The user would need read the message and note the code. Then switch back to your app where they could then type in the received code.
3. Your app can't access or modify any SMS messages received through the Messages app. The user would need to delete the message if they wanted to.